# Interchanging Supremum and Monotone Function

Tags: inequality, optimization

Let $l:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow (0,\infty)$ be a continuous function,let $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow (0,\infty)$ be continuous and monotone increasing, and let $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$.  Then is it true that
$$
f(\sup_{x \in X} l(x)) \leq f( l(sup_{x \in X}x)) ?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true. Let $\ell:[0,2]\to (0,\infty)$ defined by
$$\ell(x)=1-(x-2)x$$
Let $f:(0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ by $f(x)=x.$ Well then
$$f\left(\sup_{x\in[0,2]}\ell(x)
\right)=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}\ell(x)\geq 2>1=\ell(2)=\ell\left(\sup_{x\in[0,1]}x\right)=f\left(\ell\left(\sup_{x\in[0,1]}x\right)\right)$$

The key fact here being that $\ell$ need not attain its supremum at the endpoints (boundary if we're going higher dimensional).